# Regular expression in selenium xapth

Tags: java, selenium, regexp-replace

I would like to click on all web elements with below xpath properties.

```
    //body/div[@class='feature-flag sticky-header']/div[@class='global-nav']/nav[@class='main']/ul/li[1]
    //body/div[@class='feature-flag sticky-header']/div[@class='global-nav']/nav[@class='main']/ul/li[2]
    ....
    ...
    ...
    ....
    //body/div[@class='feature-flag sticky-header']/div[@class='global-nav']/nav[@class='main']/ul/li[10]
```

Please let me know how to write a regular expression in xapth. Below code is not working.

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//body/div[@class='feature-flag sticky-header']/div[@class='global-nav']/nav[@class='main']/ul/li.*"));
for(WebElement el:elements)
{
    el.click();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and provide a detailed explanation of the problem, along with the minimal code necessary to demonstrate the problem and your expected output. Add Error outputs as well.

Comment: You don't need a regular expression for this - you can use what you already have - just change this `/ul/li.*` to this `/ul/li`. This will find all the `<li>` elements in the targeted `<ul>` tag. I assume there is something clickable inside each `<li>` - so you may need to drill down to get the actual clickable elements. And if this does not work, then you will need to provide more information - as already noted by Naveen.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to select all the elements in th  tag then this should work:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//body/div[@class='feature-flag sticky-header']/div[@class='global-nav']/nav[@class='main']/ul/li"));
```

BUT if not and if you are sure there are 10 elements you can do that:

```
        List<WebElement> list =new ArrayList<>();
    for(int a=0; a<10; a++){
        list.add(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/div[@class='feature-flag sticky-header']/div[@class='global-nav']/nav[@class='main']/ul/li['"+a+"']")));
    }
```